# How to trace and find the clock of a certain USART for this board?

Tags: uart, clock, datasheet, diagram

I'm having trouble to trace and find which clocks clock USART2 and USART3 ect for a uC board. I looked at clock tree and block diagram of the board but cannot find a hint.

I checked both the [reference manual](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00031020-stm32f405-415-stm32f407-417-stm32f427-437-and-stm32f429-439-advanced-arm-based-32-bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf) and the [datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/dm00037051.pdf) but couldn't figure out.

(By clock I mean the clock which is clocking the USART)

Comment: Look at the example code ST provides. Off the top of my head it is probably the peripheral clock.

Comment: Im trying find a way to trace a particular USART's clock by looking at a diagram.

Comment: Read the RCC section esp the rcc_apb1 clock enable registers. The clock source for the uarts looks to be apb1 peripheral clock. The uarts sit on apb1 so that works back to the clock disgram.

Comment: I think then I should have written I am looking for a way to find the "peripheral clock source" bus for the USART.

Comment: The USARTs connected to a bus named APB142 which is also connected to APB1. (?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

USART 2 and 3 are clocked from PCLK1

datasheet page 985

> Only USART1 and USART6 are clocked with PCLK2. Other USARTs are
> clocked with PCLK1. Refer to the device datasheets for the maximum
> values for PCLK1 and PCLK2.